# Set objectAtIndex to be the integer in an NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've got this:

```
     if ([[currentPlayer rankicon] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
     self.casteImage.image = [casteImages objectAtIndex:0];
     }
```

Which works. However, I have some 16 images to assign, and since the NSString and the index id are the same, I'd like to find a more efficient way to do this. I've also tried:

```
     NSInteger i = [[currentPlayer rankicon] integerValue];
     self.casteImage.image = [casteImages objectAtIndex:[i]];
```

But that doesn't work. Could be a bug elsewhere in my code(or some syntax error in the above), of course, but was wondering if I'm anywhere near the right track.

Comment: Why is your rankicon a string when you need an integer? Why not change its type to NSInteger and save yourself all the trouble? Also it's much more efficient to convert integers to strings if you need them anywhere than to convert strings to integers all the time (although you won't notice the performance "boost" in this case).

Comment: The string is coming from an XML feed as a string, via XMLParser. Is it possible to change its type to NSInteger as it's read in? (This is my first attempt at an app, there's LOTS I don't know yet)

Comment: I'd still convert it to an integer when parsing, not when using the parsed data. First of all that would catch invalid xml when parsing it which would be easier to debug, and it also would give you the needed data later on in your code without the need to convert it all the time and abstract away the knowledge where it did come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `[]` around `i`in the second line.

Comment: Ok, I feel like an idiot now :) What's the protocol on stupid questions on this site? Can I accept your answer and then delete this?

Comment: Won't let me delete it, only flag it for moderation. Won't bother the mods--sorry again, can't believe I missed that.